# Using a nested Runnable to run stuff on the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

After discovering that Google redesigned the threading model in AsyncTask which now comes with a major bug of blocking code, I've chosen to abandon using the AsyncTask and simply use Threads and Runnables, so please don't post any comments on AsyncTask as that is not my discussion. What I would like to know is whether the following is the correct way to implement a nested Runnable that runs stuff on the UI thread:

```
private class MyOuterRunnable implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    int x = 1;

    // Do something on the UI thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        // Update a listview, etc.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

For the most part, this seems to work, but I am experiencing crashes in certain modules where I do it this way. Is this the proper way to execute UI stuff from within a nested Runnable or should I be doing it differently? All LogCat tells me is that a fatal error occurred in the nested runnable but doesn't provide any detailed info.

Comment: Post the full logcat anyway, we may be able to see more than you do.  It would be VERY unusual to not have more than that in the stack trace.

Comment: There is nothing in the logcat worth posting. It only contains a single line saying "FATAL Exception:name of class" - and that's it.

Comment: Did it crash when you excluded the runOnUiThread method from your code?